# Detecting faults on your graphics card

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card

Is there a way to set up tests/analysis of your graphics card for faults?

My issue, is that when playing games (intensive pc usage), the screen and sound freezes. The only way to over come this is via hard reset. I have used `speccy` to monitor temperatures, and nothing seems to overheat. (monitoring in real time vs logs is difficult due to having to reset.)

1. I have checked the system log for errors etc, but nothing occurs in the logs.
2. Ran memory checks on RAM
3. Ran chkdsk on harddrives

The game also becomes laggy, not long before crashing. which is Extremely unusual. It may not be the newest graphics card (GTX 460) but I've never had issues playing Dota 2 in full graphics. When i restart, and run the game, it occurs in a quicker time period. Which is why i thought it might be heat related.. But speccy says otherwise. (70c max)

If I have to go and buy a new graphics card, I would prefer to be certain its the issue first.

Comment: 70C for what ? For the video card it's quite good, for CPU its's quite bad.

Comment: @Overmind 70c on the GC. Yes, its not high, thats what im suggesting. So ruled out my over heating thoughts.

Comment: The symptoms you describe could be overheat, under-power or dying card. If it's not the first, investigate the others.

Comment: @tetsujin thanks for the info. I bought a new power supply so will see how that goes. Else resort to replacing the graphics card.

Comment: @Tetsujin In case you are interested, its been working fine since i put in a new power supply :) Got a decent , modular one. Saved me replacing the card (which wouldnt have helped anyway). Thanks.

Comment: I'll throw in something a bit like an answer - this is just one of those seat-of-the pants diagnoses, so it's rarely completely 'testable' except by swapping in replacement components. Glad you got it first try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:-

This is one of those seat-of-the-pants diagnoses, so is rarely testable by a regular user [rather than a tech with the necessary equipment] except by swapping out suspect components.

The type of hang described is a classic symptom of overheat or under-power, with an actually dying card as a long third.
As overheat had already been tested, then under-power was the next best assumption.

OP appears to have fixed the issue by replacing the PSU - so the guess/test/replace method came good first try in this case.