# Windows 10 PC Freezes and produces buzzing noise

Tags: windows-10

I built a desktop computer last year and have had various issues since that have for the most part not been resolved. My computer will freeze and produce a loud buzzing noise on a loop through my headset. The issue I seek help with today occurs when I am playing a game and watching videos(Netflix, YouTube, etc). I have read many forum posts and here is what I have tried:

1. Windows Memory Diagnostics
2. Updating and Reverting GPU Drivers
3. Getting a new GPU
4. Checking CPU and GPU temperatures

Here are some system specifications:

1. OS: Windows 10 Home
2. CPU: AMD-FX 8350
3. RAM: Kingston Hyper X Fury(2x8GB)
4. GPU: GTX 1060(previous: 960)

Comment: See this re 'seat of the pants' diagnoses - http://superuser.com/questions/1155692/detecting-faults-on-your-graphics-card - but it's either overheat or under-power. As you already tried another GPU, then PSU would be the next test, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out it is a software issue. It was Windows default drivers conflicting with the GTX 1060 drivers. Turns out the that the only way to fully delete the two drivers(even though I hunted them both down in file manager) was to reset my PC. I installed Windows again and now the drivers do not conflict. Solution: fresh Windows 10 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking "Checking CPU and GPU temperatures" during high load activities? (Netflix, YouTube, etc). Usually when people building computers themselves, they put way too much thermal-paste between CPU and heat sink which is incorrect. Layer of paste should be very thin, just to cover micro cavity on CPU and heat sink otherwise what you explaining - is classic issue when heat from CPU can't get off because of thick layer of paste.

Try to do experiment to exclude hardware issue:
Boot from [LinuxMint](https://www.linuxmint.com/) live CD (it will not damage your Windows installation) and try to do the same (Netflix, YouTube, etc). If computer will survive that, then an issue somewhere in Windows, otherwise most likely some of computer hardware is overheated during high loading.

Comment: Yes, specifically while playing games. Never goes above 45 degrees.

Comment: If it would b me, I would try live CD with another operation system, just to nail who is in charge of freezing - hardware or software

Comment: OK I will try this, however, it is a random occurrence and it is possible that the PC may not have this issue just by chance during the experiment.

Comment: Try to load LinuxMint hard, play multiple youtube videos. You can install `cpuburn` (`sudo apt-get install cpuburn` from terminal) and run it in parallel with video. If it is a hardware it should choke on it

Comment: Will try soon as possible.

Comment: is it possible this is a PSU issue?

Comment: Yes, it could be an issue too. Most of the time capacitors is in charge of such issues. If you can spot some bulged capacitor then it it is time to replace them (or get a new PSU)

Comment: just ran CPU Burn and the Valley Benchmark for GPU. The highest the two parts ever got to was 80 degrees. Didn't choke. Must be software.

Comment: Probably... Don't try to run on windows all "heavy" program all together. Run them one at time and spot that one that freeze you computer. I bet it would be some game.